# Does browser show HTML changes or allow submitting form while JavaScript is still running?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, rendering, reflow

- Given that JavaScript is running synchronously (no `setTimeout`) to add or remove HTML elements, are HTML changes supposed to be shown to the user before it's completely finished?
- More importantly, if the JavaScript is changing elements that can be included in form submission (e.g. adding multiple `textarea` elements), can user click submit button while it's in progress and submit an incomplete request? (Some `textarea` elements are included in request and some `textarea` elements are not.)

---

Something like this:
`<form action="" method="post"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>`

And when a user submit it, some function happens to be in progress.

```
function happens_to_be_running_and_user_clicks_submit(){
    the_form_element.insertBefore(document.createElement('textarea'),the_form_element.firstChild).value='first textarea value';
    the_form_element.insertBefore(document.createElement('textarea'),the_form_element.firstChild).value='second textarea value';
}
```

---

(It seems there are a lot of discussion about reflow hurting performance. But I'm still not sure if there exists any requirement or maybe it just depends on the browser. Especially about submitting form, regardless of whether it has anything to do with reflow or rendering.)

Comment: May you add a clear problem statement to your question? At the moment there are a couple of questions here, which seem to be fairly open, and are likely to attract opinionated answers.

Comment: Note that form submission are a sync like settimeout. Do you mean blocking code like a never ending while loop or actually waiting for a response from the server?

Comment: @slebetman no, just very simple javascript adding elements, e.g. adding 2 `textarea` elements to a form. Could clicking submit button submit only one `textarea` among them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion can be explained by how you've named your example function `happens_to_be_running_and_user_clicks_submit`. I presume you expect that it is possible for a function to be running when a user clicks a button.

**This is not possible**. At least not without using web workers. And even then, web workers cannot alter the DOM so by the time the web worker sends a message back to the main thread to alter the DOM it becomes impossible again.

Javascript is single threaded. Therefore only one thing can happen at a time. When a user does anything (move a window around, click a button, move the mouse..) the OS will send that event to the application's event queue. Javascript (or rather, the browser) reads this queue to process events. But since it's single threaded it only processes events when it is not busy.

So. That leaves us with ONLY two possibilities.

1. Your function somehow executes immediately before the user clicks the button. Then everything the function does will be rendered and active when the user clicks the button.
2. Your function somehow executes immediately after the user clicks the button. Then nothing the function does will be active when the user clicks the button.

There is no 3'rd state. It's either all or nothing. At least not without something asynchronous like `setTimeout` or ajax.

Comment: It should be noted that while most people's mental model of animations like fade-in or fade-out is of a single function doing it's work animations are in fact a series of functions called periodically by setTimeout or setInterval or requestAnimationFrame. So animations falls under the category of asynchronous